# How to configure Instance chat in logmein Rescue

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, chat

I am coding windows form application and using windows form application user able to connect to technician for tech support, in this case use able to initiate chat instance.

Looking this solution is Logmein Rescue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Login Logmein Rescue Administration Center, and go to **Channels** Tab, and copy **Custom Live Support Forms with self-hosted Instant Chat**

[image]

Step 2: Create new html page in windows form application and paste this html in this page.

Stpe 3: Add WebBrowser Control webBrowser1 in form application. and navigate crated new html page in this browser control

```
 public partial class InstanceChat : Form
    {
        public InstanceChat()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigate(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "logmein from.html");
        }
    }
```

Step 4: html page contains

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/InstantChat/InstantChat.aspx"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadInstantChat(){
            var ICLoader = new RescueInstantChatLoader();
            ICLoader.ICContainer = "ICContainer";
            ICLoader.HostedCSS = "https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/InstantChat/Standard/InstantChat.css";
            ICLoader.HostedLanguagesForChatOnlyMode = "https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/InstantChat/LanguagesForChatOnlyMode.js";
            ICLoader.HostedLanguagesForAppletMode = "https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/InstantChat/LanguagesForAppletMode.js";
            ICLoader.EntryID = "421042";
            ICLoader.Name = document.getElementById("Name").value; /* optional */
            ICLoader.Comment1 = document.getElementById("Comment1").value; /* optional */
            ICLoader.Comment2 = document.getElementById("Comment2").value; /* optional */
            ICLoader.Comment3 = document.getElementById("Comment3").value; /* optional */
            ICLoader.Comment4 = document.getElementById("Comment4").value; /* optional */
            ICLoader.Comment5 = document.getElementById("Comment5").value; /* optional */
            ICLoader.Tracking0 = ""; /* optional */
            ICLoader.Language = ""; /* optional */
            ICLoader.HostedErrorHandler = function(ErrorName){} /* optional */
            ICLoader.Start();}
        function handleRebootOrRefresh(){
            if ((window.location + "").indexOf("rescuewebsessionid") != -1){document.getElementById("ICContainer").style.display=""; loadInstantChat();} /* optional */
            if (window.location.hash.length == webSessionIdLength + 1){document.getElementById("ICContainer").style.display=""; loadInstantChat();} /* optional */
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="handleRebootOrRefresh();">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Please enter your name: </td><td><input id="Name" type="text" maxlength="64" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Custom Field 1: </td><td><input id="Comment1" type="text" maxlength="512" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Custom Field 2: </td><td><input id="Comment2" type="text" maxlength="512" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Custom Field 3: </td><td><input id="Comment3" type="text" maxlength="256" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Custom Field 4: </td><td><input id="Comment4" type="text" maxlength="64" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Custom Field 5: </td><td><input id="Comment5" type="text" maxlength="64" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Channel 01" onclick="document.getElementById('ICContainer').style.display=''; loadInstantChat();" />
    <div id="ICContainer" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 400px; height: 500px; display: none"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

hance chat start between techincian and client using windows from application:
[image]

Step 5: Create setup file and add html page to Application Forler of setup, so it work after installation.
[image]